# Lower level black brick staining

Tags: brick

What might be the cause of the lower level black brick staining, shown on the pictures?  What is the remedy?  I did not get up close to look at these, rather saw them when I was posting neighborhood notices for an association where I'm the board.  These are north facing units that are part of a quad-unit building.  I did not look on the south facing units to see if there was similar staining.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With it being beside a garage and running an engine inside is not usually a good idea, wondering if the people warm up vehicles, just outside with exhaust pointed that way.  Bare spot on driveway points to this idea, hot vehicle melting snow underneath.

Comment: North side, in the shade, good old natural mold. I would look on the same side of the trees and you can probably find some. VTC as this not about home improvement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not home improvement.

Comment: Looks like rising damp to me. Garage door indicates it's prone to damp & though you can't always spot a DPC by eye, it would be above the 2nd course on a UK build, so any damp/mould would only go 2 bricks high, not all the way up.

Comment: Vt Leave open - we have _ton_ of questions about mold, rot & staining, their causes and remediation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like mold/mildew due to rain splash from lack of (or clogged) gutters.

Generally, the staining is not uniform from top to bottom.